# How to remove and restore option from select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="first">
    <option value="aaa">asdf</option>
    <option value="bbb">sdf</option>
    <option value="ccc">gfd</option>
    <option value="dd2">fdg</option>
</select>
<button id="delete">delete</button>
<select id="second" style="display: none">
    <option value="aaa">asdf</option>
    <option value="bbb">sdf</option>
    <option value="ccc">gfd</option>
    <option value="dd2">fdg</option>
</select>
<button id="restore">restore</button>

$('#delete').click(function(){
    $('#first option').remove();
})

$('#restore').click(function(){
    //how to restore option for #first?
})
```

I would like remove option from select and next restore the same options as the start. I create for this auxiliary select (#second).

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PEXhX/)

Comment: hide the option when delete and when restore display the option

Comment: this not working on chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
<select id="first">
    <option value="aaa">asdf</option>
    <option value="bbb">sdf</option>
    <option value="ccc">gfd</option>
    <option value="dd2">fdg</option>
</select>
<button id="delete">delete</button>
<select id="second" style="display: none">
</select>
<button id="restore">restore</button>

$('#delete').click(function(){
    $('#first option').appendTo("#second");
})

$('#restore').click(function(){
    $('#second option').appendTo("#first");
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PEXhX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use append to return the values

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
$('#first option').remove();
})

$('#restore').click(function(){
//how to restore option for #first?
$('#first').append('<option value="aaa">asdf</option><option value="bbb">sdf</option>   <option value="ccc">gfd</option><option value="dd2">fdg</option>');
})
```